# Vercel error with youtube-dl-exec and Next js

Tags: python, node.js, next.js, youtube-dl

I'm using **Next js** and `youtube-dl-exec`. I made endpoint `/api/video/info` with Next APIs in dir `pages/api/video/info.js`

`info.js`:

```js
import youtubedl from 'youtube-dl-exec'

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { videoLink } = req.query
  if (!videoLink) {
    res.status(400).json({
      code: 400,
      message: 'Bad request: the video link is missing.',
    })
    return
  }
  try {
    const videoInfo = await youtubedl(videoLink, {
      dumpSingleJson: true,
      noWarnings: true,
      preferFreeFormats: true,
    })
    res.status(200).json({
      code: 200,
      data: {
        title: videoInfo.title,
        author: videoInfo.uploader,
        lengthSeconds: videoInfo.duration,
        viewCount: videoInfo.view_count,
        thumbnailUrl: videoInfo.thumbnail,
        description: videoInfo.description,
        formats: videoInfo.formats,
      },
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(500).json({
      code: 500,
      message: "couldn't get video information",
      error,
    })
  }
}
```

The code works perfectly on my local machine on port 3000 and even after production with command `npm run build` and `npm start` it works fine on both environment (development or production) on my local machine but after deploying it to vercel when I call the endpoint, this error appears on vercel logs with status code `500`:

```bash
Error: /usr/bin/env: python3: No such file or directory
    at parse (/var/task/node_modules/youtube-dl-exec/src/index.js:15:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async handler (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/video/info.js:35:27)
    at async Object.apiResolver (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:184:9)
    at async NextNodeServer.runApi (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:403:9)
    at async Object.fn (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:493:37)
    at async Router.execute (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:222:36)
    at async NextNodeServer.run (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:612:29)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleRequest (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:311:20)
    at async module.exports (/var/task/___next_launcher.cjs:29:9) {
  shortMessage: 'Command failed with exit code 127: /var/task/node_modules/youtube-dl-exec/bin/yt-dlp https://youtu.be/WwB5w-Rt88k --dump-single-json --no-warnings --prefer-free-formats',
  command: '/var/task/node_modules/youtube-dl-exec/bin/yt-dlp https://youtu.be/WwB5w-Rt88k --dump-single-json --no-warnings --prefer-free-formats',
  escapedCommand: '"/var/task/node_modules/youtube-dl-exec/bin/yt-dlp" "https://youtu.be/WwB5w-Rt88k" --dump-single-json --no-warnings --prefer-free-formats',
  exitCode: 127,
  signal: undefined,
  signalDescription: undefined,
  failed: true,
  timedOut: false,
  isCanceled: false,
  killed: false
}
```

What's the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure `youtube-dl-exec` needs privileges to download and install yt-dlp

So it won't work on vercel

You will have to put this in a Docker container and deploy on a server of yours, or one serverless that supports docker

Let me know if you manage to do it as I'm interested

Comment: Yeah it won't work on a serverless hosting. 
I managed to deploy my app based on ytdl-core on a VPS.